# Node.js - TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method

Tags: node.js

I am trying to include a module i found that will help manage users: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/382561/Session-Management-in-Nodejs

> Ive copied the code and put it in the same directory as my server.js

I require it by doing:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http'), 
mysql = require("mysql");
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var sessionMgm = require("./sessionManagement");
```

Now in my socket i do this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('setUserInfo', function (data) {
        var sess = new Object();
        sess.sessionId = socket.id;
        sess.userId = data.userId;
        sess.username = data.username;
        sess.role = data.role;
        sessionMgm.add(sess);
    });


    socket.on("private", function(data) { 
        if(data.agentName.length <= 0) {
            data.agentName = 'Besökare';
        }       
        io.sockets.in('Room_' + data.user_id).emit('updatechat', data.agentName, data.msg);
        var user = sessionMgm.getSessionByUserId(data.id);

        console.log('::: A socket with ID ' + user + ' connected! ::: ');
    });

});
```

However i keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'getSessionByUserId'

Cant seem to figure out whats wrong, any ideas?

sessionManagement.js:

```
module.exports = sessionManagement;

var sessions = [];

//User roles list
var userRoles = {
  Admin: "administrator",
  User: "user",
  Supervisor: "supervisor"
};

var sessionManagement = {
  indexOf: function(sessionId) {
    for(var i in sessions) {
        if(sessions[i].sessionId == sessionId)
            return i;
    }

    return null;
  },
  indexOfUser: function(userId) {
    for(var i in sessions) {
        if(sessions[i].userId == userId)
            return i;
    }

    return null;
  },

  add: function(sessionData) {
    sessions.push(sessionData);
  },
  remove: function(sessionId) {
    var index = this.indexOf(sessionId);
    if(index != null) {
        sessions.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
  },
  removeByUserId: function(userId) {
    var index = this.indexOf(userId);
    if(index != null) {
        sessions.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
  },

  getSessionById: function(userId) {
    var index = this.indexOfUser(userId);
    if(index != null) {
        return sessions[index];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
  },
  getSessionByUserId: function(sessionId) {
    var index = this.indexOfUser(userId);
    if(index != null) {
        return sessions[index];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
  },

  isAdmin: function(userId) {
    var index = this.indexOfUser(userId);
    if(index != null) {
        if(users[index].role == userRoles.Admin) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
  },
  getUsersByRole: function(role) {
    var usersByRole = [];
    for(var i in users) {
        if(users[i].role == role)
            usersByRole.push(users[i]);
    }

    return usersByRole;
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you put `module.exports = sessionManagement;` in your sessionManagement.js file? Even better: Post the code

Comment: Dident have that in there, now i get a different error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'getSessionByUserId' of undefined .. so something happend :)

Comment: @Elvin post your sessionManagement.js, otherwise we can only guess

Comment: @Elvin Put: module.exports = sessionManagement; at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As madflow mentioned, you were missing `module.exports = sessionManagement` in `sessionManagement.js`

Then you got the error, because you were exporting `sessionManagement`, before initializing it. Moving the export line to the end of `sessionManagement.js` should fix that.

```
module.exports = sessionManagement; // <- you export here
    ...
    ...
    ...
var sessionManagement = { // and initialize here
```

Although `sessionManagement` declaration gets hoisted to the top of the module (and that's why you don't get `Unexpected identifier` or `ReferenceError` when assigning it to `module.exports`),  it's initialization does not, so what really happens behind the scenes is something like that:

```
var sessionManagement;  // undefined at this point

module.exports = sessionManagement; // <- you export here, 
// but sessionManagement is undefined at this point 
// and so will be module.exports after this line
    ...
    ...
    ...
sessionManagement = { // and initialize here
```

Comment: That worked! :) Ofc now i get new errors :/     var index = this.indexOfUser(userId);
                                 ^
ReferenceError: userId is not defined

Comment: @Elvin change `sessionId` to `userId` in `getSessionByUserId` definition